# Sharing local Apache vhost over lan without Hosts/DNS change?

Tags: snow-leopard, network, development, apache, webserver

I'm freelancing somewhere and want to share a local (on my MacBook) site with some LAN users via IP. The network structure, time and technical ability here don't allow me get everyone to add host entries or setup proper DNS..

So.. say I have http://devsite accessible on my own machine, is there a way that I can access this from the LAN via IP like: 'http://10.1.2.3/devsite' ?

I see that 'http://10.1.2.3/~mbp/' works for the default site (where 'mbp' is my machine name) but not sure how to get other sites working?

Cheeeers.

Added for clarity: the name 'devsite' is added in /private/etc/hosts by me, and the vhost is added to /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you turn on Web Sharing from the System Prefs there will be a LAN IP that will point to your local ~/Sites folder. All you would have to do is have those on the LAN point there browsers to `http://myLANIP/~username/devsite` where `devsite` is a folder inside of your ~/Sites folder.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, so the reason it's not working for me like that at the moment is that my sites live in another location. Ok, I'm going to be rebuilding the machine soon so I'll have a re-jig and change the way I work :) - Thanks!

Comment: Try placing an alias to the folder where your work is into ~/Sites